# How to run my exe file from a server?

Tags: applet, webserver, xampp, exe

I am very new to web-programming things. So I need a suggestion how to implement and choosing the tools for this project.

1. I have created an exe file with "Adobe Director" which is a GUI application.
2. I want to put that application in a web-server and run it in a browser from client side.
3. My website needs username and password so it will use the MySQL for this.
4. I am planning to use XAMPP open-source server for this work.

Following are my queries
1. How I can run that exe prepared by Adobe Director? 
2. What my server should be capable of?
3. What should my client side should be capable of?

If someone can provide details steps about this and some code snipplets(for using an .exe file and preparing a java servlet) I would be grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want to create a Shockwave app with Director that can run directly in the client's browser? The way you want to do things is plain impossible.

Comment: thanks for your reply. shockwave player is client side or server side? what should i do to use the shockwave player? Do i need to install anything on client or server?

Comment: Client side. Read the docs that come with Director, search for Shockwave.

Answer (score 0):

You need Microsoft Terminal Server, and use the RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) to achive this.